# How to read specific number of messages per minute from apache kafka message queue

Tags: apache-kafka

How to read specific number of messages per minute from apache kafka message queue? For example, imagine that there are 100 messages in the queue, how can I get 5 messages to be read per minute. I don't know how to set "max.partition.fetch.bytes" as my byte size is not the same in every message.

Is there a way to dynamically set this to read 5 messages per minute?

Comment: Can you describe your problem statement that you are trying to solve here? That would help answer the question better.

Comment: What would happen if you read as many events as possible, as fast as possible?

Comment: I want to do it over time using a single thread, it should do this without tiring the system.